# Get Record - Does date exist in date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am sure this is a somewhat simple question, but for some reason I am getting really weird results. As sample of the data is (The dataset is far more complex but this is the logic behind it):

```
+-----+--------+-----------+----------+
| Key |  Name  | StartDate | EndDate  |
+-----+--------+-----------+----------+
|   1 | Name1  |  20180101 | 20180801 |
|   2 | Name2  |  20180801 | 20181205 |
|   3 | Name3  |  20181205 | NULL     |
+-----+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Now on 20180812 I want to know who was active, so I say:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 20180812 BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

This logic here is giving me a seemingly huge cross join turning my data set of 6000 into a return of millions.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong in this logic?

**------ Update -------**

I seems I need to give some information about how the dates are joined to the data table.

So for each of StartDate (INT) and EndDate (INT) are keys that link to a date dimension.

Just to clarify the query actually looks like this.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM Table T1
LEFT JOIN Dimension.[Date] [StartDate] ON T1.StartDate = [StartDate].DateKey
LEFT JOIN Dimension.[Date] [EndDate] ON T1.EndDate = [EndDate].DateKey
WHERE '2018-11-01' BETWEEN [StartDate].FullDateAlternateKey AND [EndDate].FullDateAlternateKey
```

FullDateAlternateKey is a DATE

Comment: What do you want NULL to mean? If a NULL `EndDate` means "future" then you could use `where StartDate <=20180812 and 20180812 <= Coalesce( EndDate, 20180812 )` or `where StartDate <=20180812 and ( 20180812 <= EndDate or EndDate is NULL )`. (I'm assuming that `StartDate` is never NULL.) As for the number of rows multiplying, that would be due to something that you've simplified out of the sample code.

Comment: Hi, EndDate of NULL means "Current" - Trying your query I am getting the same issue, I seem to get a record for every day after 20180812. I should add that I am left joining a Date dimension to this query, maybe that is where things are going rouge

Comment: Yes it may give you cross join values as you are just joining on dates, and each row will be true for multiple rows if that date exists, and if you have some kind of ID to join that may help you to get less rows

Comment: So it turns out I am full blown simple... Never copy and paste join statements... you might for get to change your join conditions table prefixes...

Comment: Can you provide sample data from all relevant tables that illustrates the problem? There's no way to tell really how you're getting 6000 rows, when we don't know how much that is inflating what you'd expect. Can you illustrate using the sample data you provided and whatever other supplemental data is needed to show an explosion in row count?